# Hibernate - Get "selected" and "all available" objects

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've been searching for the last 2 days, and I have to just be missing something.

I have 2 objects -

```
public class Project
int id;
ProjectStatus status;
List<ProjectStatus> statusesAvailable;
```

.

```
public class ProjectStatus
int id;
String text;
```

Properties have getters/setters.

I have no problem mapping the "status" field itself, but I cannot figure out how to map the statusesAvailable field. It just needs to contain all of the statuses that are in the ProjectStatus table. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to map this the only one object is available to you.

Comment: The list of available statuses is not a property of a specific project. You shouldn't have such an association. To get the list of all the available statuses, just use a findAll query (`select s from ProjectStatus s`).

Comment: In the past, I've kept like-data together, so I put the list of status objects right next to the list of all available status objects. There's not a way to do that in hibernate?